# How to use lang var inside handlebars loop array?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, handlebars.js, var, lang

I have codeigniter project with handlebars.js
and I have page (page.template.html) through codeigniter api I pass lang variables 
inside the page when loop with handlebars with an array I can't use the lang var because it will get form the array

is there anything to escape getting from the array .. OR any other solutions?

in the code below .. the array is (orgLang) and (this) is the element 
the array looks like:
orgLang = ['ar' ,'en']

and the lang var is (details.slug)

```html
{{#each orgLang}}
     <a class="dropdown-item lang-picker-item" href="{{details.slug}}/{{this}}">
         <img width="25px" src="assets/images/flags/{{this}}.jpg" >
      </a>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this solution and it's worked
add ../ before the variable 
because it's in another scope

```html
{{#each orgLang}}
     <a class="dropdown-item lang-picker-item" href="{{../details.slug}}/{{this}}">
         <img width="25px" src="assets/images/flags/{{this}}.jpg" >
      </a>
{{/each}}
```